# Vertically centering a responsive image

Tags: css, responsiveness

I got a image that should always fill the available space like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/0236osj6/

Is it possible to center this image - in addition to its existing behaviours - vertically with CSS? I already tried some things with tables but doesn't come to an working solution:

```
#imagedetails_image table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Problem was that the table doesn't accept the 100% height.

Comment: Do you want the image to cover the entire div area?? something  like this??    [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/letmedoit/0236osj6/2/)

Comment: no the spacing is correct as it was (and doesn't matter) ... the image should be centered vertically so that it covers the area (spacing or not) and is centered in the middle of the holder

Comment: like this one https://jsfiddle.net/0236osj6/4/ ? let me know

Comment: Looks already pretty good but there is the problem that the image is not scaled in the vertical direction ... so if the holders height is smaller than the image it will be cropped

Comment: sorry but not sure about vertical direction as how it will depend on device height. You can scroll down, image won't crop.

Comment: The image is shown within the application in a overlay window so the scrolling isn't a behaviour that should appear ... probably i try a js solution for the vertical centering

Answer (score 0):

You can set your parent element to `display:table` and your child element to `display:table-cell`. After this just give your child element a `vertical-align: middle`.

Here is an example :https://jsfiddle.net/zqgwL8tp/

Comment: Adding example from link to answer would be more helpful for future reader.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no pur CSS solution to that exact behaviour ...

Here a version with very small javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/0236osj6/5/

```
function imagedetail() {

    var container = jQuery( '#imagedetails_image' ).height();
    var image = jQuery( '#imagedetails_image img' ).height();

    jQuery( '#imagedetails_image img' ).css( 'margin-top', (container-image)/2 );

} imagedetail();

jQuery( window ).resize( function() {
    imagedetail();
} );
```

The image is now centered in all directions and never bigger than the parent container

Comment: Here a variant that waits until image is loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/0236osj6/6/